# How to show image from local folder in HTML file from Android's Google Chrome?

Tags: android, html

I'm creating an HTML file with css and java, and I want to load an image using img tag, but Android isn't loading the image when using img src="" code.
The image is the phone's Download folder of the Android phone, but I can't figure out the path I have use to load the image in the HTML.

Comment: the image needs to be on your server

Comment: It is all the same as on web. Just the relative path compared with the html file. I wonder why you did not try.

Comment: Not Android is loading but Chrome i think.

Comment: You can neglect all advices using a server.